# How to notice the playbackState of MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a moviePlayer on iPhone with custom UI. The problem is that when I play a internet video with a url, the internet status might be not so great. When the video is paused because of the internet or the video is not started because of loading data, I should let my users know that the app is loading data.

I used the notifications to do that but failed. How to notice the paused caused by internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you using notifications? Post your code.

From the sounds of it, I would check out `loadState`, `playbackState`, and register for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` and/or 
`MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` notifications.

Im not too familiar with the library, but check out the [Apple Docs on this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/)